# How to create a custom console command to migrate all migration files?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I'm creating a console command to auto-install my project. The console command needs to run `composer install`, update, etc. All those things are covered, but `Artisan::call('migrate')` to deploy the DB structure is not working. Further than this, is not doing anything. No action, no error message.

Here is the Console Command PHP file:

```php
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Artisan;

class install extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'goliatt:install';

    protected $description = 'Install Goliat Core Framework';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        // THIS WORKS
        exec('composer install');

        // THIS DOES NOT WORK
        $exitCode = Artisan::call('migrate');
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use Laravel Envoy for deployments? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/envoy

Comment: Thanks for your anwser Karl. Unfortunately, Envoy only works under MAC/Linux, and I need to cover Windows too...

Comment: Ok Fixed. It was the 'echo' instructions. Changing that for $this->info("...") instructions it's work :)

Comment: This will not work. You cannot run `composer install` from an Artisan command. Without the composer packages already installed, console commands are not runnable. They require a few dependencies of the framework and Symfony to be run. Make sure to test everything with a fresh copy of your repository.

Comment: It's working changing echo by info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. The problem was I was using 'echo' instead of info. It's working changing echo by info.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be calling the wrong Artisan. Namespace should be `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan`

Comment: I fixed. It was the echo lines. If I change the echo commands by info commands works nice :)